# Integrating Bootstrap Template into cakephp

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, templates, layout, cakephp-2.0

There are lots of peoples asked about integrating twitter bootstrap with cakephp.
i followed lots of tutorial but nothing was helped me.
I downloaded one bootstrap template for my admin panel. but i dont know how to integrate it with cakephp. i have used templates before, and i copied the css and js into

```
     app/webroot/css 
     app/webroot/js
```

and it works fine,but when i open this templates there are many folders inside it

```
     asset
     bootstrap
     venders,and some html pages
```

i don't know how to integrate it in cakephp. if anybody knows please give me a step by step procedure so that it helps all people..
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Integrating a bootstrap template in cakephp is very easy.

First copy all your css in `app/webroot/css/`.

Second copy all js in `app/webroot/js/`.

Third copy all fonts (like fontawesome) in `app/webroot/fonts/` (you will have to create this directory).

Fourth from the template cut the code from `<html>` to `</head>` and paste in a new file header.ctp under folder `app/view/elements/`.

Fifth create a file mylayout.ctp in folder `app/view/layout/`
write the following code in it

```
<?php
    echo $this->element('header');
    echo $this->fetch('content');
?>
```

sixth in your controller say UsersController.php create a function index.

```
<?php
    class UsersController extends AppController{
        public function index(){
             $this->layout='mylayout';
        }
    }
?>
```

Seventh in your header.ctp delete all `<link>` to css and instead of write

```
<?php echo $this->Html->css(array('ccs1','css2','css3'));?>
```

do the same with all the scripts

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script(array('script1','script2','script3'));?>
```

Now, create a new file index.ctp in the app/view/Users/ folder. You will have to 
create this folder.

In the index.ctp copy all the remaining code from the template file starting from `<body>` tag to `</html>` tag.

At last in your browser open `localhost/pathToYourProject/Users/`

You can also create a footer element if you want.

This is a basic example to integrate any template in cakephp.